# How can i access the different component from different windows form which are under same project in c#?

Tags: c#, mysql, database

For example in form 4 i have a data grid view and when i select a data from data  grid view and click on update.. form 5 pops up with various empty text fields. Now i wanna make sure those text fields are filled up with my data that i selected in data grid view. How can i make that happen?

say i selected 4th row in my data grid view which is

```
id = 4
name = name
address = address
```

on form 5 i have 3 text box i.e  so when form load how can i make those text box auto-filled with the data i selected in data grid view in form 4.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the best way is to write a custom constructor for your form, and pass the data to it.  Something like this:

```
 public DisplayForm(int id, string name, string address)
{
    InitializeComponent();
    //Take the data that you passed to the constructor, and use it to update the text boxes:
    txtID.Text = id.ToString();
    txtName.Text = name;
    txtAddress.Text = address;
}
```

You then call it using the constructor that you just wrote:

```
DisplayForm display = new DisplayForm(4, name, address);
```

You could even create one that takes a DataGridViewRow as an argument:

```
 public DisplayForm(DataGridViewRow row)
{
    InitializeComponent();
    //Take the data that you passed to the constructor, and use it to update the text boxes:
    txtID.Text = row.Cells[0].Value.ToString();
    txtName.Text = row.Cells[1].Value.ToString();
    txtAddress.Text = row.Cells[2].Value.ToString();
}
```